# Is it possible to run files with .vbe extension on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, wine, games, winetricks, desktop-apps

I want to run a game on Ubuntu 16.04. While I'm trying to install the game using wine software, it's not recognising the file extension.

`Setup.vbe`, is there any way to run this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "vbe" stands for Visual Basic Editor and is a script language Ubuntu does not support.

From wine you would need microsoft office and use the office part this file is made for (likely Excel).

Or you could install virtualbox, windows in that, office in that and run it from there.

Mind that "setup.vbe" on google more than once refers to malware.

Comment: Ok now got it . i was getting the same results in google..so badluck for me :(